# Erro SQLITE in android studio

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

im making a game and i need to use sqlite to database, but i had a problem this morning when i was trying to insert in a table with foreign key (see in the picture below)

[enter image description here][1]

These are my tables 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE6nL.png

These are my insert code
[enter image description here]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcHTc.png

but when i execute the application the erro appear in the select part

excuse me im noob and im starting at android (Android studio), if you can help me, thank you, but if you can´t thank you too :))))

Comment: Please put the code directly in your posts rather than in images.

Comment: What is the error which happens? Did you see anything in logcat?

Comment: Basically i have a button that when pressed call this function. I have three tables (ATIVIDADES,SOCIEDADES and TAREFASP) and the table ATIVIDADES has two foreign keys and i need to insert data in this table ATIVIDADES

Comment: this is the code of insert: String comandoBanco = "INSERT INTO ATIVIDADES(_idTarefaExecutada,_idSociedadeSelecionada,local,quantidade,data)" +
                    " VALUES(SELECT _idTarefaP FROM TAREFASP WHERE nomeTarefa LIKE 'Visita a sócios'" +
                    " ,SELECT _idSociedade FROM SOCIEDADES WHERE nomeSociedade LIKE 'UCP', '"
                    +localTexto+"', '"+quantidadeTexto+"', '"+dataTexto+"')";
            conn.execSQL(comandoBanco);

Comment: The error that appear is this:                                                                       Error to add "SELECT": sintax error(cod 1):, while compiling: INSERT INTO ATIVIDADES(_idTarefaExecutada, idSociedadeSelecionada
local, quantidade,data) VALUES(SELECT id_TarefaP FROM TAREFASP WHERE nomeTarefa LIKE 'Visita a sócios', 
SELECT _idSociedade FROM SOCIEDADES WHERE nomeSociedade LIKE 'UCP', 'Porto Canoa',
'25','07/08/17');

Comment: the values _idTarefaExecutada and _idSociedadeSelecionada are foreign keys of tables TAREFASP and SOCIEDADES

Comment: To edit the question, click "edit".